# need an idiom or phrase that means "you're up early"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms, idiom-requests

I am writing a screenplay and one of the characters picks up the phone and says "you're up early" but I need something to replace it. It doesn't have to be a real idiom or commonly used phrase as I don't think many exist (though perhaps I am mistaken). So you can be as creative as you want. For example I thought of something like "rooster's crowin" but I think it's maybe a little too cool/abstract. I need the phrase/idiom to connote that the person it's being said to is usually not up this early. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah no ELU's not a writing service.

Comment: “You’re up early” is ***exactly*** what they would say.  Why is that not good enough?

Comment: Up with the cows

Comment: Let's say the caller's name is Bob.  Then the callee might say, "Bob?  What are you doing up?  Did you have some insomnia?"

Answer (score 4):

[up with the lark](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/up-with-the-lark)

> in British English
> up early in the morning

[Bright and early](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/bright-and-early)

> very early in the morning
> *He was up bright and early, keen to get started.*

Answer (score 3):

You could try "you're an early bird", which would be derived from the common aphorism "The early bird catches the worm".

Comment: Just to comment on my answer -- the term "early bird special" is fairly common in the USA, meaning a discount is offered for people who come earlier than the busy time (for example, at a restaurant.)

Answer (score 0):

I hereby submit four possible suggestions for an alternate wording. Note that the square brackets in the fourth suggestion means optional and the "<->" squiggle means choose either. I had to presume from the wording of the posed question that, being intended for a screenplay, the poser perhaps wanted something more jaunty or colorful than what he began with. I also assume he kind of meant "My, you're up early" where I have added the "my" emphasizing the shock by the speaker at the caller's deviation from his/her norm. The posed question was not extremely precise so I applied my insights. Here then are my four suggestions:

"It's not even noon yet; what are you doing up?"

"I would expect you to be catching Z's at this hour."

"'Not sleeping **in** this morning? What's the occasion?"

"It's got to be important for you to have crawled out from the covers [so early] <-> [at this ungodly hour]."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).